# Boost::Asio Server reads blank message from client, even after the write handle finishes

Tags: c++, boost, client, boost-asio

I try to write an async message to the server from my client code, the write handler gets called with the correct bytes sent; however, the server receives 0 bytes.

Cliente output:
You are connected
You received the following message from the server:
Sat Aug 20 17:42:01 2016
Sending...

Server output:
Server is online!
127.0.0.1:51973 connected!
Client has received the messaged. 
You received the following message from the server:

server source:

```
using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

std::string make_daytime_string()
{
    using namespace std; // For time_t, time and ctime;
    time_t now = time(0);
    return ctime(&now);
}


class tcp_connection: public boost::enable_shared_from_this<tcp_connection>
{
public:
    typedef boost::shared_ptr<tcp_connection> pointer;

    static pointer create(boost::asio::io_service& io_service)
    {
        return pointer(new tcp_connection(io_service));
    }

    tcp::socket& socket()
    {
        return socket_;
    }

    // Call boost::asio::async_write() to serve the data to the client.
    // We are using boost::asio::async_write(),
    // rather than ip::tcp::socket::async_write_some(),
    // to ensure that the entire block of data is sent.

    void start()
    {
        // The data to be sent is stored in the class member m_message
        // as we need to keep the data valid
        // until the asynchronous operation is complete.

        m_message = make_daytime_string();

        // When initiating the asynchronous operation,
        // and if using boost::bind(),
        // we must specify only the arguments
        // that match the handler's parameter list.
        // In this code, both of the argument placeholders
        // (boost::asio::placeholders::error
        // and boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred)
        // could potentially have been removed,
        // since they are not being used in handle_write().

        std::cout << socket_.remote_endpoint().address().to_string() << ":" << socket_.remote_endpoint().port() << " connected!" << std::endl;

        boost::asio::async_write(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(m_message),
                                 boost::bind(&tcp_connection::handle_write, shared_from_this()));

        boost::asio::async_read(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(_buffer), boost::bind(&tcp_connection::handle_receive, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error, boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
    }


private:
    tcp_connection(boost::asio::io_service& io_service)
    : socket_(io_service)
    {
    }
    // handle_write() is responsible for any further actions
    // for this client connection.

    void handle_write() // call back.. when it finishes sending, we come here
    {
        std::cout << "Client has received the messaged. " << std::endl;
    }

    void handle_receive(const boost::system::error_code& ErrorCode, std::size_t bytes_transferred)
    {
        std::cout << "You received the following message from the server:" << std::endl;
        std::cout.write(_buffer.data(), bytes_transferred);

    }

    tcp::socket socket_;
    std::string m_message;
    boost::array<char, 126> _buffer;
};

class tcp_server
{
public:
    tcp_server(boost::asio::io_service& io_service) : acceptor_(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), 7171))
    {
        // start_accept() creates a socket and
        // initiates an asynchronous accept operation
        // to wait for a new connection.
        start_accept();
    }

private:
    void start_accept()
    {
        // creates a socket
        tcp_connection::pointer new_connection = tcp_connection::create(acceptor_.get_io_service());

        // initiates an asynchronous accept operation
        // to wait for a new connection.
        acceptor_.async_accept(new_connection->socket(),
                               boost::bind(&tcp_server::handle_accept, this, new_connection,
                                           boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    }

    // handle_accept() is called when the asynchronous accept operation
    // initiated by start_accept() finishes. It services the client request
    void handle_accept(tcp_connection::pointer new_connection,
                       const boost::system::error_code& error)
    {
        if (!error)
        {
            new_connection->start();
        }

        // Call start_accept() to initiate the next accept operation.
        start_accept();
    }

    tcp::acceptor acceptor_;
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Server is online!" << std::endl;
    try
    {
        boost::asio::io_service io_service;

        tcp_server server(io_service);

        io_service.run();

    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

client source:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

std::string make_daytime_string()
{
    using namespace std; // For time_t, time and ctime;
    time_t now = time(0);
    return ctime(&now);
}

class Connection
{
public:
    Connection(boost::asio::io_service& io) : _socket(io){}

    void connect(tcp::resolver::iterator& point)
    {
        boost::asio::async_connect(_socket, point, boost::bind(&Connection::onConnected, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    }

    void onConnected(const boost::system::error_code& ErrorCode)
    {
        std::cout << "You are connected" << std::endl;

        // receive first message on onReceive
        boost::asio::async_read(_socket, boost::asio::buffer(_buffer), boost::bind(&Connection::onReceive, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error, boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
    }

    void onSend(const boost::system::error_code& ErrorCode, std::size_t bytes_transferred)
    {
        std::cout << "Sending..." << std::endl;
    }

    void onReceive(const boost::system::error_code& ErrorCode, std::size_t bytes_transferred)
    {
        std::cout << "You received the following message from the server:" << std::endl;
        std::cout.write(_buffer.data(), bytes_transferred);

        // send first message on onSend
        m_message = make_daytime_string();
        boost::asio::async_write(_socket, boost::asio::buffer(m_message), boost::bind(&Connection::onSend, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error, boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
    }

    tcp::socket& getSocket()
    {
        return _socket;
    }
private:
    tcp::socket _socket;
    boost::array<char, 126> _buffer;
    std::string m_message;
};

int main()
{
    try
    {
        boost::asio::io_service io_service;

        tcp::resolver resolver(io_service);

        tcp::resolver::query query("127.0.0.1", "7171");

        tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator = resolver.resolve(query);

        Connection conn(io_service);
        conn.connect(endpoint_iterator);

        io_service.run();
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

@edit:

new client code:

```
    class Connection : public boost::enable_shared_from_this<Connection>
{
public:
    typedef boost::shared_ptr<Connection> pointer;

    static pointer create(boost::asio::io_service& io_service)
    {
        return pointer(new Connection(io_service));
    }


    tcp::socket& socket()
    {
        return _socket;
    }

    void connect(tcp::resolver::iterator& point)
    {
        boost::asio::async_connect(_socket, point, boost::bind(&Connection::connect_handler, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    }

    void connect_handler(const boost::system::error_code& error)
    {
        if(error)
        {
            std::cout << "Error on connect_handler: " << error.message() << std::endl;
            return;
        }

        std::cout << "You are connected to the server." << std::endl;
        start();

    }

    void start()
    {
        start_write();
        start_read();
    }

private:
    // private ctor
    Connection(boost::asio::io_service& io) : _socket(io){}

    void start_write()
    {
        _daymessage = make_daytime_string();

        boost::asio::async_write(_socket, boost::asio::buffer(_daymessage),
                                 boost::bind(&Connection::handle_write, shared_from_this(),
                                             boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                                             boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
    }

    void handle_write(const boost::system::error_code& error,
                      size_t bytes)
    {
        if(error)
        {
            std::cout << "Error on handle write: " << error.message() << std::endl;
            return;
        }

        std::cout << "Message has been sent!" << std::endl;
        start_write();
    }

    void start_read()
    {
        // Start an asynchronous operation to read a newline-delimited message.
        boost::asio::async_read_until(_socket, _buffer, '\n',
                                      boost::bind(&Connection::handle_read, shared_from_this(),
                                                  boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                                                  boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
    }

    void handle_read(const boost::system::error_code& error, size_t bytes)
    {
        if(error)
        {
            std::cout << "Error on handle read: " << error.message() << std::endl;
            return;
        }

        // Extract the newline-delimited message from the buffer.
        std::string line;
        std::istream is(&_buffer);
        std::getline(is, line);

        if (!line.empty())
        {
            std::cout << "Received: " << line << "\n";
        }

        start_read();
    }

    tcp::socket _socket;
    std::string _daymessage;
    boost::asio::streambuf _buffer;
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Client is running!" << std::endl;

    try
    {
        boost::asio::io_service io_service;

        tcp::resolver resolver(io_service);

        tcp::resolver::query query("127.0.0.1", "7171");

        tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator = resolver.resolve(query);

        auto connection = Connection::create(io_service);

        connection->connect(endpoint_iterator);

        io_service.run();
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

obs: I got a "tr1::bad_weak_ptr" when I use public ctor and instantiate with make_shared. The private ctor and static member func worked fine.

Comment: put on the source code in your question.

Comment: I didn't know exactly what I was asking, bit lost. Now I have refactored the question and topic, please take a look on the new edit if you will.

Comment: this is true, okay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many issues with the code you have provided:

- In your server connection class, you are using raw `this` pointer
  instead of using `shared_from_this`. This was resulting in the
  operation getting `cancelled` as your resource was getting out of
  scope.
- The code is making use of `async_read` with a buffer of size 126. I
  guess the operation would not finish until you receive atleast that
  many bytes. Use `async_read_until` instead. Due to lack of any protocol or predefined byte sequence, I have modified the code
  to send '\n' as the delimiter.
- Never ignore the error code received.

Modified Server Code:

```
class tcp_connection: public boost::enable_shared_from_this<tcp_connection>
{
public:
    typedef boost::shared_ptr<tcp_connection> pointer;

    static pointer create(boost::asio::io_service& io_service)
    {
        return pointer(new tcp_connection(io_service));
    }

    tcp::socket& socket()
    {
        return socket_;
    }

    // Call boost::asio::async_write() to serve the data to the client.
    // We are using boost::asio::async_write(),
    // rather than ip::tcp::socket::async_write_some(),
    // to ensure that the entire block of data is sent.

    void start()
    {
        // The data to be sent is stored in the class member m_message
        // as we need to keep the data valid
        // until the asynchronous operation is complete.

        m_message = make_daytime_string();

        // When initiating the asynchronous operation,
        // and if using boost::bind(),
        // we must specify only the arguments
        // that match the handler's parameter list.
        // In this code, both of the argument placeholders
        // (boost::asio::placeholders::error
        // and boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred)
        // could potentially have been removed,
        // since they are not being used in handle_write().

        std::cout << socket_.remote_endpoint().address().to_string() << ":" << socket_.remote_endpoint().port() << " connected!" << std::endl;

        boost::asio::async_write(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(m_message),
                                 boost::bind(&tcp_connection::handle_write, shared_from_this()));
        boost::asio::async_read_until(socket_,
            _buffer,
            '\n',
            boost::bind(&tcp_connection::handle_receive,
              shared_from_this(),
              boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    }


private:
    tcp_connection(boost::asio::io_service& io_service)
    : socket_(io_service)
    {
    }
    // handle_write() is responsible for any further actions
    // for this client connection.

    void handle_write() // call back.. when it finishes sending, we come here
    {
        std::cout << "Client has received the messaged. " << std::endl;
    }

    void handle_receive(const boost::system::error_code& ErrorCode)
    {
        std::cout << "You received the following message from the server: "<< std::endl;
        if (ErrorCode) {
          std::cout << "Error occured: " << ErrorCode.message() << std::endl;
          return;
        }
        std::string line;
        std::istream is(&_buffer);
        std::getline(is, line);
        std::cout << line << std::endl;

    }

    tcp::socket socket_;
    std::string m_message;
    boost::asio::streambuf _buffer;
};
```

Modified Client Code:

```
class Connection: public boost::enable_shared_from_this<Connection>
{
public:
    Connection(boost::asio::io_service& io) : _socket(io){}

    void connect(tcp::resolver::iterator& point)
    {
        boost::asio::async_connect(_socket, point, boost::bind(&Connection::onConnected, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    }

    void onConnected(const boost::system::error_code& ErrorCode)
    {
        std::cout << "You are connected" << std::endl;

        // receive first message on onReceive
        boost::asio::async_read_until(_socket,
            _buffer,
            '\n',
            boost::bind(&Connection::onReceive,
              this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    }

    void onSend(const boost::system::error_code& ErrorCode, std::size_t bytes_transferred)
    {
        std::cout << "Sending..." << std::endl;
    }

    void onReceive(const boost::system::error_code& ErrorCode)
    {
        std::cout << "You received the following message from the server:" << std::endl;
        //std::cout.write(_buffer.data(), bytes_transferred);

        // send first message on onSend
        m_message = make_daytime_string() + '\n';
        std::cout << "Sending " << m_message << std::endl;
        boost::asio::async_write(_socket, boost::asio::buffer(m_message), boost::bind(&Connection::onSend, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error, boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
    }

    tcp::socket& getSocket()
    {
        return _socket;
    }
private:
    tcp::socket _socket;
    boost::asio::streambuf _buffer;
    std::string m_message;
};
```

Comment: First I want to thank you for your reply.

It worked pretty good; however: I tried to leave the constructor public, and instantiate the class with make_shared, and passing a shared_from_this() to all the handlers. It did not workout, and I received a "tr1:bad_weak_ptr". So what I did, I have declared a private ctor, and used a static function to instantiate the class and return a shared pointer for that object, as same as on the server. And now I have a shared_ptr on the main related to the object. It is working. Do you think is good like that, or a refactor may be better? And why tr1:bad?

Comment: I have posed the new code on the main topic so you can see

Comment: @BrunoMiguel I still see your `connect` method using a raw `this` pointer instead of `shared_from_this`. I am not sure why you were hitting `bad_weak_ptr` but what you suggested looks fine to me. The only logical problem I see is that, the client is now issuing multiple `start_write` requests but the server (as per the original code you posted) only reads it one time.

Comment: Technically the server will not go out of scope until the io_server.run() terminates, for that being said, is it really necessary to derive the server class from enable_shared... and pass a sharedfromthis() instead of this to maintain the life term of object until handler be called? Because if you think about, the io.run() guarantees that all handles are called before it gets done. True or not true?

Comment: If you make sure that the IO objects are created in `main` and its life time outlives the statement `io.run` then, no, you dont have to do all those `shared_from_this` stuff. But if your, IO object was created in some other scope, then you have to make sure the IO object's lifetime outlives the scope if you are to make any `async` calls. In this case you need to create a shared_ptr and pass its instance by `shared_from_this` for which you will need to derive it from `enable_share_from_this`. Hope it's clear now.

Comment: First, thank you for taking your time and clarifying the situation. This answer is pretty clear. So I think it would be the best to use shared_from_this even if the object outlives in the statement io.run, because doing so, if in the future I decide move these methods somewhere else, or in another thread for example, I will not have to go back and fix the overhead. Is deriving from shared_from_this and using its methods make a really heavy difference on the process and memory overall, so it would worth do the overhead to sometimes avoid it?

Comment: You got it. The overhead of `shared_from_this` is basically all the overhead that a shared_pointer has i.e atomic reference counting. Which would not be that much considering you are writing an asynchronous system. If you plan not to use this, you would anyways end up writing something similar but also a less efficient version.

Comment: Something really interesting happened. Tried to write the server code being shared_from this based, and it invoked the client ctor by accepting a connection that has not even attempt to connect to it. Program throw a weak_ptr and crashed.

Comment: It would be better if you open a new question for that.